# Javascript Нажатие кнопки на странице в браузере в определённое время

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Мне нужно организовать нажатие кнопки на веб-странице в определённое время, которое я задам. Код, который я вставляю в консоль хрома не работает, потому что видимо проблема в грамматике. Буду благодарен, если укажите на мою ошибку 
Код на Javascript:

```
    window.setInterval(function(){ // Интервал проверок
var date = new Date();
if(date.getHours() === 8 && date.getMinutes() === 0){ 
    document.querySelector('.button-submit).click()
}
}, 1000); // Повторять проверку каждую секунду
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После .button-submit не закрыли кавычку:

```js
window.setInterval(function(){ // Интервал проверок
var date = new Date();
if(date.getHours() === 8 && date.getMinutes() === 0){ 
    document.querySelector('.button-submit').click() // <-- вот здесь
}
}, 1000); // Повторять проверку каждую секунду
```

И еще учтите, что в течении той минуты, в которой у вас состоиться клик, всю минуту будет кликаться по кнопке, а не один раз.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо